# 3-sphere complex co-ordinates

Tags: general-topology, differential-geometry, projective-geometry

I am currently trying to understand some mathematical physics papers that deal with torus knots.

I am trying to find the origin of a complex scalar field used. These fields are somehow related to the Hopf fibration.

I have spent the last week reading about and trying to understand the Hopf fibration. I Believe I understand the Hopf fibration with the mapping of $h(z_1,z_2)\mapsto \frac{z_2}{z_1}$.

Multiple papers are stating this:

$$u = u(r) = \frac{(r^2 −1)+2iz)}{r^2 +1},\ \ \   v = v(r) = \frac{2(x +iy)}{r^2 +1}$$

As the "standard complex co-ordinates for the 3-sphere". I am unable to find this information anywhere else apart from these papers, and I need to find out where it arises from, as to me this doesn't make sense.

I am a 2nd year physics undergraduate and if you could explain in a way I can understand, that will be awesome!

Here is one paper - the rest are behind paywalls https://arxiv.org/pdf/1302.0342.pdf Eq (10)

Comment: is it standard complex co-ordinates for the $2$-sphere instead? Also, it would be better to link to some of the paper where this term shows up.

Comment: What do you mean by "is it standard complex co-ordinates for the 2-sphere instead?"

Comment: Nothing, I think I understand the notation now.

Comment: It actually calls these the standard stereographic cooardinates for a chart on $S^3$. The problem with calling them complex coordinates is it sounds like you are calling a 3-dimensional manifold a complex manifold, which doesn't make sense. (But it can be fruitful to consider $S^3$ as a subset of $\mathbb{C}^2$.)

Comment: I dont fully understand what a "chart" is currently, or a manifold for that matter lol. I have been considering S^3 as C^2 with |z1|^2+|z2|^2 = 1. But i dont understand how these co-ordinates are obtained.

Answer (score 0):

The following answer is not rigorous. To make it rigorous you may need to know more about smooth manifold.

$\mathbb S^3 = \{ (u, v) \in \mathbb C^2 : |u|^2 + |v|^2  =1\}$ is itself a $3$-manifold, which means that locally it looks like an open sets in $\mathbb R^3$. Mathematically speaking, it means that for each point $p\in \mathbb S^3$, there is a parametrization $ \phi : U \to \mathbb S^3$ (where $U$ is open in $\mathbb R^3$), which is at least an injective mapping (with some other condition), so that $p\in \phi (U)$. This is called a (local) chart on the manifold, as you are giving for each points in $\phi (U)$ a coordinate $(x, y, z)$.

Of course this three numbers $(x, y, z)$, which is associated with the point $\phi(x, y, z)$ in $\mathbb S^3$, depends on the chart $\phi$. But $\mathbb S^3$ is so explicit that it has a "standard" chart, given by stereographic projection.

The stereographic projection is a mapping $(x, y, z)\mapsto (u, v) \in \mathbb S^3$ given by your formula, where $(x, y, z) \in U :=\mathbb R^3$ and $r = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2 + z^2}$.

One needs to check that the above mapping is really a chart (that is, it is injective). One can use the following observation about the construction of stereographic projection: given $(x, y, z) \in \mathbb R^3$, the point $(u, v)$ in $\mathbb S^3$ is formed by the intersection of $\mathbb S^3$ with the line joining $(x, y, z, 0)$ to $(0,0,0,1)$. See the picture [here](https://www.google.com.hk/search?q=Stereographic_projection&tbm=isch&imgil=4HTDIAi4My8ZwM%253A%253B1kYAeTascKSRNM%253Bhttp%25253A%25252F%25252Fwww.math.ubc.ca%25252F~cass%25252F%25252Fcourses%25252Fm309-01a%25252Fmontgomery%25252Findex.html&source=iu&pf=m&fir=4HTDIAi4My8ZwM%253A%252C1kYAeTascKSRNM%252C_&usg=__A9HPabxsvjYwkfw7b6QfKiX_YtQ%3D&biw=1366&bih=667&ved=0ahUKEwiolpeagJfOAhWCl5QKHTeTCCMQyjcIMA&ei=h2uaV-i2JIKv0gS3pqKYAg#imgrc=eb2YL5QQYuMWYM%3A) for the two dimensional picture.

Comment: That kind of makes sense. the problem is, I dont know how to get from the standard stereographic projection co-ordinates to this, I was under the impression the that the SG projection was \sigma = (x1/1-x4),(x2/1-x4),(x3/1-x4), and the inverse \sigma ^-1 = (2X/1+X^2+Y^2),(2Y/1+X^2+Y^2),(-1 + X^2 + Y^2/1+X^2+Y^2+Z^2). where i have used the hopf map to project from (z1,z2) set C2 --> z2/z1 PC1